# How to launch OWASP-ZAP desktop from the docker container

Tags: docker, zap

I want to create a .yaml file for automated testing of a CI/CD infrastructure using OWASP-ZAP.

The first recommendation seems to be [to test manually and locally](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tR93F-llbo8)... So
I would like to launch ZAP desktop from within a docker file... How should I do this?

I would need to run ZAP in the docker, that proxies from a browser... In theory, I can see two roads to follow...

1. ZAP is running in the container and so is the launched browser
2. ZAP desktop is running in the container, but the browser is running on the local computer...

Since both options need ZAP desktop screen to be exported to localhost, I guess (1) should be easier? (Is desktop included in the image? Is a browser?)

Comment: I'm curious, what other desktop apps are you able to use from within docker? https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/webswing/ & https://www.zaproxy.org/blog/2021-02-03-run-zap-without-java-using-docker-and-webswing/